# Problem with paths accessing CSS with Spring and Apache FreeMarker

Tags: java, html, css, spring, freemarker

I'm having a problem trying to access my static CSS resources from lower directories. If I am in the main directory it detects everything but if I go to other lower directories, it adds the path from that folder and does not detect them.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYpfb.png)
(In that path "server" is a directory that should not appear, since css is in the main directory)

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS
    ============================================ -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

I tried from putting ../, ./ searching the internet but I didn't find anything.

I am using Apache FreeMarker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`..`** to indicate the parent directory:

**`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">`**

**`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/font-awesome.min.css">`**

This will help you.

Comment: No, same error.    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css"> and "server"  appears again

Comment: I do not have, but also my level of spoken English I do not think it is enough ... I'm sorry but thank you very much for your offer

Comment: Try with this `href="../../bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: Same error, probably Spring or FreeMarker have another way of working

Comment: @Alex Error you showed in that image it's belongs to `JS` file not with `CSS`

Comment: It is true, problem was in JS link not CSS, I am blind xd